# Why isn't this PHP parsing XML correctly?

Tags: php, html, xml, parsing, yahoo-weather-api

I am attempting to parse Yahoo's weather XML feed via [this](http://www2.voegeli.li/no_cache/code-tutorials/php-scripts/class-weather-v2.html) script. The parsing itself works: I am just struggling with getting the days to correspond with today, tomorrow and the day after.

The final HTML output looks like this:

Which can be seen here: http://www.wdmadvertising.com.au/preview/cfs/index.shtml

```
todayMon______________19

todayTue______________26

Tue______________26
```

It is supposed to look like this:

```
Today______________(temp)

(tomrrow)______________(temp)

(day after tomorrow)______________(temp)
```

The PHP and HTML:

```
<div class="latest-weather">
    <h1 class="latest-weather">Latest weather</h1>

    include("class.xml.parser.php");
    include("class.weather.php");

$weather_adelaide = new weather("ASXX0001", 3600, "c", $cachedir);

    $weather_adelaide->parsecached(); 

    // TODAY 1

    for ($day=0; isset($weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]); $day++) {
    print "<h2>today".$weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]['DAY']."</h2>";     
    print "<p />".$weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]['HIGH']."<br>"; }

    // FORECAST 2

    for ($day=1; isset($weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]); $day++) {
    print "<h2>".$weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]['DAY']."</h2>";     
    print "<p />".$weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]['HIGH']."<br>"; }

    // FORECAST 3   

    for ($day=2; isset($weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]); $day++)  {
    print "<h2>".$weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]['DAY']."</h2>";          
    print "<p />".$weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]['HIGH']."<br>"; }

?>

</div><!--/latest-weather-->
```

Comment: Well, your code seems a bit messy. for start, why do you use "for" conditions like that? Also, you seem to be closing paragraph statements without starting them at all. About the code, does the weather xml provide the timestamp / numeric date for the days, or just string values?

Comment: @yoda: The paragraphs are OK. `</p>` closes a paragraph whereas `<p />` opens *and* closes the paragraph. It's the `<br>`s that worry me.

Comment: Sorry guys, I am a bit of a n00b at this business :) Please forgive me!

Answer (score 2):

Either you're not very clear on how `for` loops work or you've just made a really silly error.

In case of the former, remember that

```
for($x=0; isset(blah); $x++) {
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
$x = 0;
while(isset(blah)) {
    ...
    $x++;
}
```

It looks like you are *only* getting forecasts for today and tomorrow; your first loop produces:

```
todayMon______________19

todayTue______________26
```

Your second loop produces:

```
Tue______________26
```

And your third loop produces nothing.

You should probably change your code to something like this:

```
// TODAY 1

if (isset($weather_adelaide->forecast[0])) {
    print "<h2>today</h2>";
    print "<p />".$weather_adelaide->forecast[0]['HIGH']."<br>";
}

// More days

for ($day=1; $day < 3 && isset($weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]); $day++) {
    print "<h2>".$weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]['DAY']."</h2>";
    print "<p />".$weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]['HIGH']."<br>";
}
```

Another comment: I see you using `<p />` however you also use `<br>`, this is puzzling. `<br>` is not valid XHTML.

Comment: Thanks Artelius, you are right - I am unclear how for loops work! Your code seems to do the trick. How would I add the next day? I have tried duplicating the last block and changing "$day=1" to "$day=2". This didn't work.

Comment: Also, duplicating the last block of code without changing $day doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that the data you are provided with only contains a forecast for today and tomorrow. The for loop currently will go up to the 3rd day (due to $day < 3) but if there is no data to start with it obviously can't be shown...

Answer (score 0):

I assume `$weather_adelaide->forecast[0]` and `$weather_adelaide->forecast[1]` are set so you get your first `for` to print 2 times and your second to print one. I think you need `if` and not `for`: (not tested)

```
// TODAY 1
$day = 0;
if(isset($weather_adelaide->forecast[$day])) {
    print "<h2>today".$weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]['DAY']."</h2>";     
    print "<p />".$weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]['HIGH']."<br>"; 
}

// FORECAST 2
++$day;
if (isset($weather_adelaide->forecast[$day])) {
    print "<h2>".$weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]['DAY']."</h2>";     
    print "<p />".$weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]['HIGH']."<br>"; 
}

// FORECAST 3       
++$day;
if (isset($weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]))  {
    print "<h2>".$weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]['DAY']."</h2>";              
    print "<p />".$weather_adelaide->forecast[$day]['HIGH']."<br>"; 
}
```

But I would go with a `foreach(range(0, 2) as $i)` and handle the special today case with a `if`